# Is this JQuery deferred working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

Here is the line of code in question:

```
$.when(dashboard.update.call(this)).then(dashboard.updateCompleted);
```

The problem is, `dashboard.update` calls another series of 5 or so functions.  Does `dashboard.update` finish after it has finished calling those functions or after those functions have actually finished?

The reason I ask is because it seems like `dashboard.updateCompleted` is being called before the functions called from `dashboard.update` have completed.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: it depends on whether those functions uses async execution.. ie whether they have ajax request etc within them

Comment: You'll have to show us what `dashboard.update()` does (does it have async operations) and whether it returns a promise that is resolved only when the async operations are done.  `$.when().then()` can only do it's job for async operations inside of `dashboard.update()` if `dashboard.update()` returns a promise that is resolved only when the async operations are done.  And, if it does that, you don't need `$.when()` either as you can just use `dashboard.update.call(this).then(...)` directly.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the functions inside of dashboard.update are async or not... they are a series of ajax requests though.

Comment: Welp, AJAX literally has async in its name... so yes those functions do use async execution.

Comment: @Hubrid Perhaps, see also approach here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23862173/2801559

Comment: Simple question.  Does `dashboard.update()` return a promise?  If not, then it will not work with `$.when()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use when(), you must pass a defered object to the functions in when().

I just seen very similar situation with you. What I have done to make the code work is :

```
$.when(func1($.Deferred()),
       func2($.Deferred()),
       func3($.Deferred()),
       func4($.Deferred())
).done(function() {
    alert('Finished!');
}
```

And in each function, resolved() or rejected() must be called to notify $.when(). For example,

```
function func1(def) { 
    A_async_call(function (status) {
        if (status == OK) {
           def.resolve(); /// Tell $.when, this function finished
        } else {
           def.reject();  /// tell $.when, a function failed
        }
    })
    return def; // return defered object to when, for later use
}
```

Comment: You hardly ever pass deferreds-to-be-resolved around. Having the `def` as a parameter *and* returning it looks like an antipattern to me.